# How to fix values missed by MYSQL auto_increment

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table, where (to an already existing table) I added another column "Number" that is auto_incremented and has a UNIQUE KEY constraint.
There are 17000+ records in the table. After adding the "Number" column, one value is missed - there is a value of 14 369 and the next one is 14 371.
I tried removing the column and adding it again, but the missing value is still missing. 
What might be the problem, and what is the least painfull way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no problem and there is nothing to fix.**

MySQL's `auto_increment` provides **unique** values, and it calculates them using *sequential increment algorithm* (it just increments a number).

That algorithm guarantees the fastest and accurate way of generating unique values.
That's its job. It doesn't "reuse" numbers and forcing it to do so comes with disastrous performance and stability.

Since queries do fail sometimes, these numbers get "lost" and you can't have them back.

If you require sequential numbers for whatever reason, create a procedure or scheduled event and maintain the numbers yourself.

You have to bear in mind that MySQL is a transactional database designed to operate under concurrent access. If it were to reuse these numbers, the performance would be abysmal since it'd have to use locks and force people to wait until it reorganizes the numbers.

InnoDB engine, the default engine, uses primary key values to organize records on the hard drive. If you were to change any of the values, it would start re-writing the records incurring a HUGE I/O wait that depends on the amount of data on the disk - it could bring the whole serve to a grinding halt.

### TL:DR; there is no problem, there is nothing to fix, don't do it. If you persist, expect abnormal behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however your explaination is not clear to me. I understand that from the uniqueness standpoint a missing auto_increment value is not an error. However, I genuinely NEED the auto-increment value to not miss any number, so what you're saying is that there is no other way to achieve it other than doing it myself? Sounds unpractical for thousands of records...

Comment: In cases where you require sequential numbers, you have to ensure that there's only 1 process ever that handles it (no concurrency issues, thus no locks are required). Then, you start maintaining the number on your own. `auto_increment` isn't designed to behave the way you need it, thus it's not the right tool for you. The question is - are you 100% sure you need it to be sequential? If yes, your best option is to create a MySQL stored procedure that you call when performing inserts which yields numbers that can be reused.

Comment: Thanks, will try MYSQL stored procedure. I dont need concurrency since records will be written to the table rarely and by one process only. I store financial data, and need to get records which are f.ex. 20 rows after the one interesting to me. My way of doing it was to number the rows and get a record with a number that is +20. Missing values totally spoils it for me.

Comment: I'd only suggest that you keep primary key as `auto_increment` and alter the table with additional column which will be `sequence_id`. That way you get best of both worlds with the least invasive approach. Good luck!